# SPEL how to protect against injection attacks

Tags: java, spring, el, spring-el

some code like this

```
    StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    context.addPropertyAccessor(new EmptyValueMapAccessor());
    context.addPropertyAccessor(new MapAccessor());
    context.addPropertyAccessor(DataBindingPropertyAccessor.forReadOnlyAccess());
    ExpressionParser paser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression expression = paser.parseExpression("#{T(java.lang.System).exit(0)}", new TemplateParserContext());
    expression.getValue(context,obj);
```

It will execute `exit` method.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `SimpleEvaluationContext` instead - it is specifically designed for this purpose.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-evaluation-context

> `SimpleEvaluationContext` is designed to support only a subset of the SpEL language syntax. It excludes Java type references, constructors, and bean references. It also requires you to explicitly choose the level of support for properties and methods in expressions. By default, the create() static factory method enables only read access to properties. You can also obtain a builder to configure the exact level of support needed, targeting one or some combination of the following:

> - Custom PropertyAccessor only (no reflection)

> - Data binding properties for read-only access

> - Data binding properties for read and write