# SPEL Injection Security concerns for using SPEL

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, code-injection, spring-el

We are planning to use SPEL in our SaaS based product to execute conditional expressions. My requirement is to use evaluate conditions where user can write conditional expressions using variables, constants and standard functions. So, far I have used SpelExpressionParser() parser to parse the expression and then StandardEvaluationContext() to create context and then used expression evaluate to evaluate the expression.

```
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("(#Tag.matches('52.*') && #Name.toUpperCase().matches('DEF.*') ");
    EvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    context.setVariable("Tag", "57345");
    context.setVariable("Name", "defg");
    Boolean result = (Boolean) exp.getValue(context);
```

This works fine for all my requirements but my security team has concerns regarding using StandardEvaluationContext(). StandardEvaluationContext() can be exploited for SpEL Injections and can be used for Remote method Invocation using Java RMI. Here are some security concerns:

SpEL Injection attacks:
https://0xn3va.gitbook.io/cheat-sheets/framework/spring/spel-injection

OSWASP article on EL Injection attacks:
https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Expression_Language_Injection

We are suggeted to use SimpleEvaluationContext() where I see the limitation that I cannot use standard java functions and user defined functions(May be I am not clear if there is way to use it).

I am planning to use latest 2.7.x version of spring framework and Java 11 in my code.

Can someone guide me to understand:

1. Safer way to use StandardEvaluationContext() where I can disable certain Java functions like RMI and System functions so that I can safely use in our product?
2. If SimpleEvaluationContext() is the way to go, then can someone help me to use standard functions and user defined functions?

Comment: what about answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69820458/spel-how-to-protect-against-injection-attacks) also there are some references to documentation.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiLisa . That did help to understand how the StandardEvaluationContext can be exploited but using SimpleEvaluationContext will not really fulfil my requirements as it does not allow me to use methods/functions.

Comment: if you will give more context(what is going to do with user input) I might help you with another alternative to do it.

Comment: My requirement is that user should be able to enter a conditional expression and based on conditional expression evaluation result, we are going to take certain action on every row of data. A very simple example could be: Say, we have dataset with Name, Age, Phone, Email and Promotion fields. Now, if user enters a condition like ((Age > 30) && (Age < 50)) and the condition is evaluated true, we update the Promotion column with true else update it with false. OfCourse, the condition and action can be more complex and will vary. Hope, that makes thing a bit clearer.

Comment: hey, i added an answer, can you check this one approach and tell me if it meet your requirements ? also i think it is a good way based on descriptions of question and comments.

Answer (score 0):

After some details, you can change the approach and avoid using `SPEL` in this case and instead of it use [Java Bean Validation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/validation/beanvalidation.html) and create a custom one.

Something like this:

Declare a `ValidatorValues` annotation with `Target` as a `TYPE`

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidatorValuesImpl.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidatorValues {

  String message() default "All good";

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

Create an impl of it where your are going to check the conditions into `isValid` method, here as example i put your case from comments, by the way always this method will return true because we use it as a `value generator` not a `constraint validator`

```
public class ValidatorValuesImpl implements ConstraintValidator<ValidatorValues, Dataset> {

  @Override
  public void initialize(ValidatorValues constraintAnnotation) {
    ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Dataset value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    value.setPromotion((value.getAge() > 30) && (value.getAge() < 50));
    //.... others conditions

    return true;
  }
}
```

Data set also from comments example, here i set `@JsonIgnore` at `promotion` field because it is set dynamic based on user input.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ValidatorValues
public class Dataset {

  private String name;

  private Integer age;

  private String phone;

  private String email;

  @JsonIgnore
  private Boolean promotion;
}
```

And also the controller layer where it will be used when the request come to back-end side:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/endpoint")
public class DataSetController {

  private final Validator validator;

  public DataSetController(Validator validator) {
    this.validator = validator;
  }

  @PostMapping("/test")
  ResponseEntity<String> createDataset(@RequestBody @Valid Dataset eventRequestBody) {
    validator.validate(eventRequestBody);

    return ResponseEntity.ok("promotion: " + eventRequestBody.getPromotion().toString());
  }
}
```

Some test cases postman request/response:

1. Where age not pass the validation: should return promotion `false`:

[image]

2. Where age pass the validation : should return promotion `true`:

[image]